# How can I use @Transactional in multithreaded environment

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am doing a insert operation using multi threading. I used the annotated my method is`@Transaction` annotation. But I am not able to do the insert operation getting below exception.

> Exception in thread "Thread-21" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: Show that method and its invocation.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no code... In order to get it to work you must

1. Annotate your delete method with @Transactional - lets call it `delete`
2. Invocation of that method must be from outside of the bean in order for AOP to kick in

So internal invocations like

```
void doSomething(){
    this.delete();
}
```

will not work

but

```
@Autowired
YourBean bean;

...
bean.delete();
```

will do the job

Answer (score 1):

Because spring beans are wrapped you have to call the wrapped method from a Thread:

```
@Autowire
private final MyService ms=null;

public void removeMultithreaded(int[] userIds){
  for(int i =0; i< userIds.length; i++) {
    int userId=userIds[i];
    new Thread(()-> ms.delete(userId)).start();
  }
}
```

In this code you call `delete` what must be annotated by a `@Transactional`.

**Be warned:** The amount of userIds you can delete at the same time is limited by the size of the Connection Pool! Since the delete operation might be faster than the gathering and releasing from a connection pool you might never come into trouble, even if you have to remove a higher amount of users than the Connection Pool allowes.

Comment: That is rly bad to teach (probably a youngster) bad habbits of running thread yourself whenever you need instead of using workers pool.

Comment: A workers pool vs connection pool might produce a deadlock. But it is interesting what answer is upvoted. :)

Comment: from that point of view separate threads and worker pool is the same thing. Worker pool is about reusing costlycreated threads. If you say its deadlock prone, so is your answer

Comment: @Antoniossss Seperate threads are not limited in count, a deadlock is very unlikely. A full worker-pool who do not accept more work against the connection-pool will produce a deadlock for sure.

Comment: well hardware limits it. so thats the same. you can use cached pool executor which can go wild and create maximum possible thread count.

Comment: what? worker will just wait for connection. no deadlock there

Comment: having w workers and c connections. if w>c workers will wait. if c>=w no waiting. Where is the deadlock to you?

Comment: so if your tasks will require more than one connection without releasing previous one, then it will be deadlock prone in high concurency env. but separate thread will not help you with that nor any other multithreading configuration. That will be a bug. Thus your argument is invalid as long as fetching connection is atomic connections are released

Comment: @Antoniossss Ah ok, you mean if the cp and wp are different pools. I use springs wp as cp, thats my confusion. I remember tomcat use DBCP in resource-registration, thats what you might meant.

Comment: but connection pool (connections) incomparable to workers pool (threads). one if set of connections that can be borrowed and anotjer is collection of threads that can ezecute tasks. it cannot be the same. if you are calling connection pool a set of threads that executes tasks on db than this is origin of the confusion. wp are threads, cp are resources.

Comment: I think think that mine connection pool is not what you mean. But yes those are separate (to me always)

Comment: But i guess we are on the same page now.